# How can I enable electric indentation for all modes except some?

Tags: init-file, hooks, major-mode, electric-indent

I am trying to enable electric-indent-mode for all modes except fundamental-mode, where it is just annoying. In my init file, I have the following:

```lisp
(electric-indent-mode +1)
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda ()  (if (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
                          (electric-indent-mode -1))))
```

This, however always disables electric-indent-mode because the value of major-mode is always 'fundamental-mode when the hook is invoked. Seems that the value of that variable is changed AFTER the hook is called? Makes no sense to me.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve this? There is no fundamental-mode-hook unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

`electric-indent-mode` is a global mode, so if your function *ever* gets invoked, it will disable it everywhere.

You then also have the problem that if the global mode is enabled, new buffers which are never given a new major mode at all will have that behaviour, because the hook you're using never runs.

`electric-indent-local-mode` is the equivalent buffer-local minor mode, so I think you should *disable* the global mode, and instead *enable* the local mode everywhere you want it, which you can do using much the same technique you've shown in your question.

```el
(electric-indent-mode 0)

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'my-electric-indent-local-mode-maybe)

(defun my-electric-indent-local-mode-maybe ()
  "Enable `electric-indent-local-mode' if appropriate."
  (unless (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
    (electric-indent-local-mode 1)))
```

I'll add that the local mode turns out to be a hack of the global mode, such that as far as `describe-mode` is concerned it's the global mode which is active or inactive on a per-buffer basis.  This is pretty confusing when testing :)

---

You could alternatively do this:

```el
(defun my-electric-indent-rules (_char)
  "Used with `electric-indent-functions'."
  (when (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
    (setq electric-indent-inhibit t) ;; Prevent future attempts.
    'no-indent)) ;; Deny the current attempt.

(add-hook 'electric-indent-functions #'my-electric-indent-rules)
```

I don't recommend it for your case though, because it's having to process things every time it might need to indent something, as opposed to configuring the behaviour once per buffer.

(Thanks to Andrew Swann for pointing out that we could make this latter approach more efficient in the `fundamental-mode` case by also setting `electric-indent-inhibit`.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toggling the `electric-indent-mode` directly you can set the variable `electric-indent-inhibit`:

```el
(electric-indent-mode t)
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 
          (lambda ()  (if (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
                          (setq electric-indent-inhibit t))))
```

This variable is buffer local.

Comment: `after-change-major-mode-hook` isn't necessarily called in the buffers they are interested in.

Comment: @phils I see.  I worked in the cases I tested, but as you say the buffers may be created in different ways.  Would it perhaps be best to change your code to set this variable, which then inhibit further attempts to electric indent in the buffer, and so be run only once.

Comment: That's a good idea; I'll add that.